# How to export C# file (in visual studio) with filled in const strings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, export, constants

Is there a way to copy/export the Main.cs file so that the constants are already filled in?
I'd like to have a new file (Main.cs - Copy) where the constants are filled in.

MyConsts.cs

```
public const string str1 = "field1";
public const string str2 = "field2";
```

Main.cs

```
static void Main()
{
    DoSomething(str1, "description of field1");
    DoSomething(str2, "description of field2");
}
```

Main.cs after export.

```
static void Main()
{
    DoSomething("field1", "description of field1"); //filled in const
    DoSomething("field2", "description of field2"); //filled in const
}
```

Why I want to do this:
I need to make resources that follow a certain convention, like key: [ClassName].field1.Description value: "description of field1". I have written a script that eases the copy paste work, but I need the literal string "field1" and not the str1 const to make the resource, And thus make my script work.

Comment: If you have resharper you can inline it. Just out of curiosity - why do you want to do that?

Comment: Sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295). What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to make resources that follow a certain convention like  
res: [ClassName].field1.Description value: "description of field1"
i have written a script that eases the copy paste work, but I need the literal string "field1" and not the str1 const to make the resource. :)

Comment: @Sinatr I could formulate my real "big" problem directly but i feel that it detracts from the simple problem/solution.

Comment: That's the trap: you think your solution is correct and simple, but it's not. It looks like you are re-inventing localization to me, so I'd just suggest you to look into existing approaches. Personally I prefer to have dedicated class with localizable text, which you can easily export/import using reflection without need of compiler services like in your case.

Comment: @Sinatr I'm not in the position to choose how localization should be done. I can edit the post so that it includes my whole problem. But it would be less concise and less helpfull for others. If you still like to help me. I will reedit my post to include everything. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code to export C# file (in visual studio) with filled in const strings.

Initial .cs file.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoSomething(MyConsts.str1, "description of field1");
            DoSomething(MyConsts.str2, "description of field2");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static void DoSomething(string field,string description)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}+****+{1}",field,description);
        }
    }
}
```

Code to export it:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string quote = "\"";
            var text = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Program.cs");
            text = text.Replace("MyConsts.str1", quote+MyConsts.str1+quote).Replace("MyConsts.str2", quote + MyConsts.str2 + quote);
            File.WriteAllText("D:\\test.cs", text);
        }
    }
```

Finally, you will get the result:

[image]